# new database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cannot create a new database in SQL Server 2008 rc2. Says that it cannot connect to the server, instance-specific or network-related error is displaying. Remote connection is enabled.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx    - needed the 3rd download option, problems fixed. Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to create the database? Via SSMS? If so, via context menu or via a query? If via a query (either through SSMS or SQLCMD, or otherwise), what's the exact text of your query?

Comment: I have just installed sql server 2008 rc2, and I am trying to create a database in the SQL Server management studio

Answer (score 1):

1. Is SQL Server running?
2. Is it on the same machine as your client?
3. If no to (1) & (2), then is there some firewall between the two, preventing traffic via port 1433?
4. If no to (3), then do your current user credentials have permissions to connect up to SQL Server?

What's the exact full error message?  With all error codes? (Severity, State etc...)

Comment: TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to CHRIS-PC.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: I had used sql server 2008 without any issues before, when sql server 2008 rc2 was installed I have had problems connecting

Comment: and that is on the same host as you?

Comment: yes I am using the same computer as the sql server is running on

Comment: Is it a named instance or a default instance?  And does your connection string reflect that?

Comment: its using the default instance

Comment: @Chris, check if the `Named Pipes` protocol for the server is running. This is available through All Programs > SQL Server 2008 R2 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager. In the network configuration node, check the Protocols node - Named Pipes. This should be Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot connect at all?

First check with the Sql configuration manager that the Sql server service is running.

Comment: yep the service is running and set to automatic startup

Comment: Perhaps the server name has changed. When you get the 'connect to server' dialog, can you open the dropdownlist with 'server name' and click on browse for more. Do you see your SQL Server there?

Comment: When i click browse for more there is none under local tab, the same one is under the network servers tab under database engine.